# Dropdown select in form not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu

This is my first question on this site.  I have an issue with Internet explorer.  My contact form works fine in Chrome, Safari and FF but not in IE.  Here is the [link](http://www.new.djd-training.com/demo.php) for my form.

Basically the problem(s) are that there is no text in the dropdown select and as a consequence, nobody can send an enquiry via IE.  Can someone help me out here?

Other information...
I got the fancy contact form from:
http://tutorialzine.com/2009/09/fancy-contact-form/
There are other smaller issues such as width of the selects are different in various browsers but I only care about the above problem.

Many thanks

Comment: I see a jquery invalid arg error in IE8

Comment: You are using a minified version of javascript file which is very difficult to track down. Please use a complete version so that I can help.

Comment: I don't have access to IE at the moment to confirm, but this seems like a hasLayout issue to me. Your select boxes are being turned into unordered lists, and list-items are often the first thing needing zoom:1 or height:1% (in my experience).

Comment: what version(s) of IE are you testing with? (this is vital information!)

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple errors in the code. I would suggest using a javascript debugger. Chrome developer tools has a good one, and

[Firebug is good too for Firefox](http://getfirebug.com/javascript)

for Chrome:

Control - Shift - I keys to open Developer Tools

Control - Shift - J to open Developer Tools and bring focus to the Console.

Control - Shift - C to toggle Inspect Element mode

Answer (score 0):

In your code there are missing commas and parenthesis for if statements... though those are not needed by the compiler, it's good practice to always wrap if statements inside commas, and always put semicolon at the end of each row.

For example

```
$("#contact-form").validationEngine({
        inlineValidation: false,
        promptPosition: "centerRight",
        success :  function(){use_ajax=true},
        failure : function(){use_ajax=false;}
     }) // missing semicolon here
```

and

```
{

    $.validationEngine.buildPrompt(".jqTransformSelectWrapper","* This field is required","error") // missing semicolon here
    return false;
}
```

Since you are having bad arguments call in the debugger, it's better to write the code the right way, then we can try to understand what's wrong.